# Writing unit tests with JsonSerializerOptions that was injected into a class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit

Per [this blog post](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/inject-jsonserializeroptions-so-dont-repeat-yourself), I thought it would be a neat idea to try and re-use JsonSerializerOptions, as I noticed newing up of `JsonSerializerOptions` showing up in multiple classes.

```csharp
// Program.cs
services.AddSingleton<JsonSerializerOptions>(new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        });
```

And I am injecting this into my class, like this

```csharp
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger, 
IConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection, 
JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    this.redisConnection = redisConnection;
    this.options = options;
}
```

But when I try to write a unit test for this, I can't because `JsonSerializerOptions` is a sealed class:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock (JsonSerializerOptions) must be an interface,
a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.
```

Comment: Its probably easiest to just construct a new instance of `JsonSerializerOptions` in your tests, instead of trying to mock/fake it

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. I don't really do anything with it in this class except just pass it in when I call Serialize()...Thanks!